# Two Java classes to perform similar queries with caching

Tags: java

I have two Java classes with very similar code. Basically they are almost the same except for  a few method calls etc, i.e. replace `ip` with `msisdn` in the classes and they would be identical.

How can I refactor them to remove the duplication? Or maybe if there is a Design Pattern I should be using?

```
public class IpQuery {

    private final CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface;

    private final CSVFileReader csvFileReader;

    private final XMLFileReader xmlFileReader;

    private final CacheQueryRequester cacheQueryRequester;

    private final CacheQueryResponseParser cacheQueryResponseParser;

    /**
     * Invokes a cache query using the ip as a key into the session cache, displaying the result on the command line.
     * <p>
     * @param   ipToQueryCacheFor the ip to query the PCC-A session cache for.
     * @param   commandLineInterface object used to display error/warning/info messages on the command line.    
     */
    public IpQuery(String ipToQueryCacheFor, CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface) {
        this.commandLineInterface = commandLineInterface;

        this.csvFileReader = new CSVFileReader(commandLineInterface);

        this.xmlFileReader = new XMLFileReader(commandLineInterface);

        this.cacheQueryRequester = new CacheQueryRequester();

        this.cacheQueryResponseParser = new CacheQueryResponseParser();

        queryCacheForSessionWithIp(ipToQueryCacheFor);
    }

    private void queryCacheForSessionWithIp(String ipToQueryCacheFor) { 
        final String configFile = commandLineInterface.getConfigFileArgValue(); 

        if (configFile != null) {

            if (configFile.endsWith(".xml")) {

                final ArrayList<String> pccaPoolHosts = xmlFileReader.read(configFile);

                queryPrimaryAndSecondaryPCCAForIp(ipToQueryCacheFor, pccaPoolHosts);
            } else {
                final ArrayList<String> pccaPoolHosts = csvFileReader.read(configFile);

                queryPrimaryAndSecondaryPCCAForIp(ipToQueryCacheFor, pccaPoolHosts);
            }
        } else {
            commandLineInterface.displayMessage(
                    "Warning: No CSV or XML config file entered, defaulting to querying localhost [::1].");

            invokeCacheQueryForIp(ipToQueryCacheFor, "::1");
        }
    }

    private void queryPrimaryAndSecondaryPCCAForIp(String ipToQueryCacheFor, ArrayList<String> pccaPoolHosts) {
        final PCCAServerSelector pccaServerSelector = new PCCAServerSelector(pccaPoolHosts, ipToQueryCacheFor);

        commandLineInterface.displayMessage(
                "Info: Querying primary PCC-A [" + pccaServerSelector.getPrimaryEndpoint().getIPAddress() +"]");

        invokeCacheQueryForIp(ipToQueryCacheFor, pccaServerSelector.getPrimaryEndpoint().getIPAddress());

        commandLineInterface.displayMessage(
                "Info: Querying secondary PCC-A [" + pccaServerSelector.getSecondaryEndpoint().getIPAddress() +"]");

        invokeCacheQueryForIp(ipToQueryCacheFor, pccaServerSelector.getSecondaryEndpoint().getIPAddress());
    }

    private void invokeCacheQueryForIp(String ipToQueryCacheFor, String pccaHostToQuery) {
        final PayLoad cacheQueryResponsePayLoad = cacheQueryRequester.queryCacheForSessionWithIp(ipToQueryCacheFor, pccaHostToQuery);

        final String cacheQueryResponseAsString = cacheQueryResponseParser.parse(cacheQueryResponsePayLoad);

        commandLineInterface.displayMessage(cacheQueryResponseAsString);
    }
}
```

```
public class MsisdnQuery {

    private final CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface;

    private final CSVFileReader csvFileReader;

    private final XMLFileReader xmlFileReader;

    private final CacheQueryRequester cacheQueryRequester;

    private final CacheQueryResponseParser cacheQueryResponseParser;

    /**
     * Invokes a cache query using the msisdn as a key into the session cache, displaying the result on the command line.
     * <p>
     * @param   msisdnToQueryCacheFor the msisdn to query the PCC-A session cache for.
     * @param   commandLineInterface object used to display error/warning/info messages on the command line.    
     */
    public MsisdnQuery(String msisdnToQueryCacheFor, CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface) {
        this.commandLineInterface = commandLineInterface;

        this.csvFileReader = new CSVFileReader(commandLineInterface);

        this.xmlFileReader = new XMLFileReader(commandLineInterface);

        this.cacheQueryRequester = new CacheQueryRequester();

        this.cacheQueryResponseParser = new CacheQueryResponseParser();

        queryCacheForSessionWithMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor);
    }

    private void queryCacheForSessionWithMsisdn(String msisdnToQueryCacheFor) {     
        final String configFile = commandLineInterface.getConfigFileArgValue(); 

        if (configFile != null) {

            if (configFile.endsWith(".xml")) {

                final ArrayList<String> pccaPoolHosts = xmlFileReader.read(configFile);

                queryPrimaryAndSecondaryPCCAForMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, pccaPoolHosts);
            } else {
                final ArrayList<String> pccaPoolHosts = csvFileReader.read(configFile);

                queryPrimaryAndSecondaryPCCAForMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, pccaPoolHosts);
            }
        } else {
            commandLineInterface.displayMessage(
                    "Warning: No CSV or XML config file entered, defaulting to querying localhost [::1].");

            invokeCacheQueryForMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, "::1");
        }
    }

    private void queryPrimaryAndSecondaryPCCAForMsisdn(String msisdnToQueryCacheFor, ArrayList<String> pccaPoolHosts) {
        final PCCAServerSelector pccaServerSelector = new PCCAServerSelector(pccaPoolHosts, msisdnToQueryCacheFor);

        commandLineInterface.displayMessage(
                "Info: Querying primary PCC-A [" + pccaServerSelector.getPrimaryEndpoint().getIPAddress() +"]");

        invokeCacheQueryForMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, pccaServerSelector.getPrimaryEndpoint().getIPAddress());

        commandLineInterface.displayMessage(
                "Info: Querying secondary PCC-A [" + pccaServerSelector.getSecondaryEndpoint().getIPAddress() +"]");

        invokeCacheQueryForMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, pccaServerSelector.getSecondaryEndpoint().getIPAddress());
    }

    private void invokeCacheQueryForMsisdn(String msisdnToQueryCacheFor, String pccaHostToQuery) {
        final PayLoad cacheQueryResponsePayLoad 
            = cacheQueryRequester.queryCacheForSessionWithMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, pccaHostToQuery);

        final String cacheQueryResponseAsString = cacheQueryResponseParser.parse(cacheQueryResponsePayLoad);

        commandLineInterface.displayMessage(cacheQueryResponseAsString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to remove the multiple blank lines from the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right the only difference is this line:

```
final PayLoad cacheQueryResponsePayLoad 
        = cacheQueryRequester.queryCacheForSessionWithMsisdn(msisdnToQueryCacheFor, 
            pccaHostToQuery);
```

ant the `CacheQueryRequester` class could be similar to the following:

```
public class CacheQueryRequester {

    public PayLoad queryCacheForSessionWithMsisdn(final String msisdnToQueryCacheFor, 
            final String pccaHostToQuery) {
        ...
    }

    public PayLoad queryCacheForSessionWithIp(final String ipToQueryCacheFor, 
            final String pccaHostToQuery) {
        ...
    }

}
```

To remove the duplication I'd change the `CacheQueryRequester` to an interface with only one method:

```
public interface CacheQueryRequester {

    public PayLoad queryCacheForSession(final String queryCacheFor, 
            final String pccaHostToQuery);
}
```

And create two implementations: `IpCacheQueryRequester` and `MsisdnCacheQueryRequester`. Finally, rename one of the original query classes simply to `Query` and modify its constructor to the following:

```
public Query(final String queryCacheFor, final CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface, 
        final CacheQueryRequester cacheQueryRequester) {
    ...
    this.cacheQueryRequester = cacheQueryRequester;
    ...
}
```

Now, you can pass an `IpCacheQueryRequester` or an `MsisdnCacheQueryRequester` instance to the constructor and get rid of the other query class.

Answer (score 2):

From memory I think Eclipse does an "Extract Supertype" which might help you pull out a base class. Using inheritance may not be the best way of solving this but it will at least give you the common code.